# Adding AnchorPanes to ScrollPanes Javafx 8

Tags: javafx, java-8, blurry

in JavaFX, when I add an AnchorPane that has a Label inside to a ScrollPane, the whole AnchorPane comes in a tad blurry, as  if it had a Photoshop-feather effect. I am using Java8 the latest release. This was not the case with Java7.
Have you ran into this issue before?

Comment: No. Can you post a small example reproducing this issue?

Comment: Show us some code and may be a screen shot of how your screen looks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar problems following a java 8 upgrade:

1. Using JavaFX Scene Builder, I noticed that under Layout: Position, I had Layout X / Y a non zero value (like 9.893739 etc). when I replaced those with 0, the blurry text went away.
2. Try removing any anchor pane constraints. I've found weird calculations being done that is causing the width/length to be weird fractions and causing blurriness

Comment: Here's the [official bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089499). The problem seems to be non-integers in any of the layout properties. This seems to include *padding* as well as *layoutX/Y*.